# How can I create a stripchart with mean represented as a short line instead of dot in R?

Tags: r, line, mean, stripchart

I would like to create a stripchart that looks like this:

[image]

But I was only able to create something similar using stat_summary crossbar:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + 
stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult=1), geom="crossbar", width=0.5) +
geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))
```

The result is this:

[image]

I would be grateful for any advice on how to modify the code so I can get a graph like in the first image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **beeswarm** package:

```
library (beeswarm)

beeswarm(len ~ dose, data = ToothGrowth, 
    col = 4, pch = 16,
    main = 'beeswarm + bxplot')
  bxplot(len ~ dose, data = ToothGrowth, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), qsec)) +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = 'mean_sdl', geom = 'errorbar', width = 0.3) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = 'point', size = 20, shape = '_')
```

[image]